# How do I populate a MS Access Query with a value of a Text Box

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have two properties and each property has it's own table for orders. So I am trying to generate a query to show me all the orders for the property that is select from a text box.

So the query is as follows:

```
    Select * from Orders_Property1
```

This query works.

However, I now want the query to return the result based on the property selected on a text box. I trying:

```
    Select * from [Forms]![frm_ORDERS]![txt_PROPERTY]
```

I am getting a Syntax error. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

Fields and tables must be static in Access SQL.